# API home document using json-home

Tags: json, api, rest, web

I am developing a small web api in PHP and try to make it as restful as possible.
Currently i'm working on some kind of a "homepage" which should be a json represented overview of what the client can do without having to read a documentation. I discovered the json-home format (see [draft-nottingham-json-home-02](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-nottingham-json-home-02)) what seems to be quite useful in my case. But since it's not spread that much it's hard to find examples. What I don't understand is what the "href-vars" - attribute is (see [4.1. Resolving Templated Links](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-nottingham-json-home-02#section-4.1)).

For example I have a route /api/documents/{id} what gives me the json representation for one single document. Obviously this is a template-link resource in json-home format, but what would be my href-vars : { id: } ?

Answer (score 0):

HREF-VARS is used to specify a parameter for URL Templating.
The URI is firstly a unique identifier for the parameter. The URL *could* contain documentation regarding the type of the parameter.